# How can I capture the HttpResponseMessage.Content after a PostAsJsonAsync for our records?

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous

We're posting JSON to a service that records actions when a change is made from our website.  After posting the JSON, we'd like to capture the Content from the response message to record it.

In the Visual Studio watch pane I can see the Content, which looks something like this after a post:

> Id = 4, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "[]"

The above result appears after this statement in watch:

> httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), ac

But whenever I attempt to assign the response content to a string, the string value is merely "[]", instead of the list of properties (ID, Status, etc) I expected to see above.

Here is a simplified section of code (try/catch and other pieces omitted). After the PostAsJsonAsync, we get a 200 success status code.

```
public HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage { get; set; }
public string httpResponseMessageContent { get; set; }

private async Task SendMaintenanceEvent(object maintenanceEvent)
{
    string endpointAddress = "http://whereever";
    string targetDirectory = "OurTarget";
    string credentials = "Omitted";
    string credentialsBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(credentials));
    string maintenanceEventAsJSON = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(maintenanceEvent);
    StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(maintenanceEventAsJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpointAddress);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", credentialsBase64);
        this.httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(targetDirectory, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Current value: "[]"
            // Expected value: Id = 4, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "[]"
            this.httpResponseMessageContent = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Error sending maintenance event.");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would appear that the Content of the response message is "[]", as seen in the result variable.  If you want the ID, Status, etc, those are all direct children of the httpResponseMessage, just like Content is.  When you are creating a response from a web service, you are adding several other things in addition to any (optional) content you want to include.  Try to capture the entire httpResponseMessage as a variable, and use a helper method to parse the properties you want into a string.

Comment: Thanks Elemental Pete.  Those properties didn't appear in httpResponseMessage. However, this returns what I was expecting. The salient difference is that I removed the await:  var content = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  And as you noted, it looks like I'll need to parse through these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Id = 4, Status = RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", Result = "[]"` is debug view of completed async `Task` not the result of POST. The actual result of POST is just the `Task.Result` property (or get using `await` keyword). Result of POST is really just `[]` an empty JSON array. You client code is OK, check the server.

Comment: Try change to this and debug: `var task = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); string r = await task;`